# Perl regex to filter digits within the string

Tags: regex, perl

I do have a string as below.I am trying to filter out only the 4 digit from the string.

Ouput should be : 1234 4567 3466

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  -w 

use strict ; 

my $str = "1234asdc345r4567srsrs45678rrrffgg3466";

my @arr =$str =~/(\d{4})/g;
```

The issue is I get the output as : 1234 4567 4567 3466.
I do not want the 5 digit to be included in the output.

Comment: It looks like you should be getting `1234 4567 4567 3466`?

Comment: thanks , i updated the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pattern `\d{4}` currently does partial matches as well, which is why you're not getting the expected output. You can use lookarounds to tell that you're looking for 4 digit numbers that aren't preceded or followed by numbers:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)
```

- Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yS7fG6/1
- More about lookarounds: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Still i get the output as 1234 4567 5678 3466 :(

Comment: @SudhirMishra: I've updated the answer to include a demo. Can you check that?

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain so I can improve the answer?

Answer (score 4):

I think the cleanest way is to find all subsequences of decimal digits, and then discard those that aren't four characters long

And by the way, you should `use warnings 'all'` in preference to `-w` on the command line or shebang line

Like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.10;

my $str = '1234asdc345r4567srsrs45678rrrffgg3466';

my @arr = grep { length == 4  } $str =~ /\d+/g;

say "@arr";
```

#### output

```
1234 4567 3466
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought capture brackets were necessary in the regex, but this clearly works.

Comment: @Sobrique: They're not needed in the case of a global match

Comment: It works because it returns all the occurances of full matches of the pattern, as opposed to only the captured part, if it's less than the full pattern.

Comment: @simbabque: Sorry, *should be* what?

Comment: @simbabque: Ah I see. However a non-global pattern match in list context will return the captures if there are any, but won't return the whole matched string if there are not

Answer (score 3):

`\d{4}` is a substring of a 5 digit sequence, which is why it matches.

Anchor your pattern, and it'll work:

```
my $str = "1234asdc345r4567srsrs45678rrrffgg3466";

my @arr = $str =~/(?:^|\D)(\d{4})(?:\D|$)/g;
print join ( "\n", @arr );
```

Captures 4 digits with a non-digit(or start/end of line)  on either side.

```
1234
4567
3466
```

Comment: You can use negative look-around assertions instead of all that nasty alternation `my @arr = $str =~ / (?<!\d) \d{4} (?!\d) /xg`